# Build number mismatch of iOS parent app and app clip

Tags: ios, apple-appclips, ios-targets

I want to set the `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` of my app clip target dynamically. It should match that of the parent/main app. I tried two solutions:

- I added Run script to the app clip target in Build Settings as follows:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $GL_BUILD_NAME" "$INFOPLIST"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $GL_BUILD_NUMBER" "$INFOPLIST"
```

But this doesn't set the `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` of the app clip target. I still get build number mismatch error while archiving.

- I also added User-Defined variables (`APP_VERSION` and `APP_BUILD`) in Project Build setting and set the Current Project Version and Marketing Version in Build settings of the project. The main target and app clip then read these values and app archives fine. The problem is that I cannot set `APP_VERSION` and `APP_BUILD` to be reading from an environment variable.

Any help would be appreciated.